# Which process/script/application if squeezing my files every 5 minutes?

Tags: bash, cron, centos6, synchronization

I have a process executing every 5 minutes (precisely) which overwrites the content of a folder. It obviously synchronizes whith another (identified) folder, which means it completely replaces the content of the folder with content of the other folder. The kind of thing that rsync or unison do (which we both use).

I looked in the crontab, and after deactivating the only script executed every 5 minutes, nothing changed. So it's another process.

How could I find which script/process/thing is responsible for that behavior?

My system is CentOS 6.

Comment: try lsof as a basic tool for example

Answer (score 0):

Typically cron logs which jobs get executed so check the cron log files, usually found in `/var/log`

Then there are usually three  classes of cron jobs:

- personal cron specifications ; made by/for a specific user with `crontab -e` ; those usually get stored in `/var/spool/cron`
- system cron jobs, which get started from `/etc/crontab`. In addition to the batches specified there that crontab usually also runs  the `/etc/cron.[daily|hourly|weekly|monthly]` scripts.
- most current cron implementations support the  `/etc/cron.d/` drop-in directory to create batches. Those batches can have custom schedule and support the user column also found in `/etc/crontab` to specify a specific user ID that will be used to execute the batch.

When you can't find a cron job:

- Slowly becoming slightly more common: systemd timers. Check with `systemctl list-timers --all`
- There are quite a few other job schedulers as well, wikipedia has a whole bunch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software

Consider that the job is not running on the system where that folder lives, maybe the job is triggered remotely. Check for logins to identify the user.